# Difference between TOTAL_CONNECTIONS in MON_GET_INSTANCE and REM_CONS_IN and LOCAL_CONS in SYSIBMADM.SNAPDBM in IBM DB2

Tags: db2-luw

I am going to calculate current number of connection to IBM DB2
there is two table that include statistics of connections. one of them is MON_GET_INSTANCE that include TOTAL_CONNECTIONS: "Current number of connections to database and is collected from the MON_GET_INSTANCE."
the other is SYSIBMADM.SNAPDBM that has LOCAL_CONS and REM_CONS_IN. The sum of REM_CONS_IN and LOCAL_CONS show the number of connection to the database. As I checked these two approach to calculate number of connections are very different.
what is the difference of TOTAL_CONNECTIONS in MON_GET_INSTANCE and has LOCAL_CONS and REM_CONS_IN in SYSIBMADM.SNAPDBM?

I run SELECT (LOCAL_CONS +  REM_CONS_IN) As TOTAL_CONS FROM SYSIBMADM.SNAPDBM; with result 23 and at the same time i run select TOTAL_CONNECTIONS from Table(MON_GET_INSTANCE(-2)); that result 1.
they are very different.

Comment: The instance might have more than one active local database, and each active local database can have its own connections. The instance-level counters can differ from database-level counters in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MON_GET_INSTANCE` function doesn't show system applications, while the `SNAPDBM` one does.
If you want to get total connections count from the `MON_*` family, you may sum up the result of the following queries to each of your local databases. The last parameter (1) instructs the function to show system applications as well.

```
SELECT COUNT (1) 
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_CONNECTION (NULL, -2, 1))
```

Note, that there is no corresponding parameter for the `MON_GET_INSTANCE` function.